# PySide One slot to multiple widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am creating a small app in python using PySide.  I read lines from a text file and display each line in a separate QLineEdit Widget. Each "entry" has 2 line edits and 2 QPushButtons. For every line I add those widgets.  My problem is that I set a signal-slot for the QPushButtons, but when all the "entries" are generated, only the last entries QPushButtons connects to the slot.  May someone please help me.

Here is my code

```
class ItemLogger(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui.Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(ItemLogger, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.parseBossItem()
    self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.parseBossItem)
    self.increase.clicked.connect(self.add_subtract)


def add_subtract(self):
    initial = 1
    print "kajskasdjflsdkjflk"

def addRow(self, item):
    self.frame  = QtGui.QFrame()
    self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    self.itemName   = QtGui.QLineEdit(item)
    self.itemName.setReadOnly(True)

    self.itemCount  = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    self.itemCount.setText("0")
    self.itemCount.setMaximumWidth(40)

    self.decrease   = QtGui.QPushButton("-")
    self.increase   = QtGui.QPushButton("+")

    self.layout.addWidget(self.itemName)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.itemCount)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.decrease)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.increase)

    self.frame.setLayout(self.layout)

    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame)



def parseBossItem(self):
    if self.comboBox.currentText() == "Item_1":
        item_list = open("BossItems/Random_Item")
        for line in item_list.readlines():
            self.addRow(line)

    if self.comboBox.currentText() == "Item_2":
        item_list = open("BossItems/Random_Item_2")
        for line in item_list.readlines():
            self.addRow(line)
```

Comment: It seems there are missing things in your code. Do you call `addRow` only once, or once for each entry? Where do you call `addRow`? What are `setupUi` and `parseBossItem` function?

Comment: I call addRow() for each line in the file I am parsing.
I call addrow() in the parseBossItem function (as you can see), and the setupUI is what setups the PySide UI Interface. parseBossItem is my slot, for my currentIndexChanged signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you only connected the last entry.

Here is what you are actually doing:

1. You add row for item 1, and assign button widgets to `self.decrease`, `self.increase`.
2. You add row for item 2, replacing values of `self.decrease`, `self.increase` by newly created widgets.
3. You connect `self.increase`, which is now the last added widget.

If you don't need access to you widgets after their creation, you should consider using local variables (e.g. without `self`) and connecting the signal inside the `addRow` function.

If you need to keep track of widget references, then you could add them to an array:

```
# Somewhere in __init__ or in parseBossItem
self.increase = []

# in addRow
self.increase.append(QtGui.QPushButton("+"))
self.layout.addWidget(self.increase[-1])
self.increase[-1].clicked.connect(self.add_subtract)
# and so on...
```

---

To use the same slot form different senders, you need to identify who sent the signal. You could do something like this:

```
def onIncrease(self):
    button = self.sender()
    if isinstance(button, QtGui.QPushButton):
        buttonName = button.text()
        if buttonName == 'name of button 1':
            self.itemCount[0].setText(str(int(self.itemCount[0])+1))
        elif buttonName == 'name of button 2':
            ...
```

Off course, this is assuming you put each QLineEdit in the array `self.itemCount`.

---

Since all your buttons have the same name, we need to use another approach.

```
# in addRow
self.increase.clicked.connect(lambda: self.onIncrease(itemCount))

def onIncrease(self, edit):
    edit.setText(str(int(edit.text()+1))
```

Comment: would you also know how to increment a number in itemCount, when the appropriate pushButton is pressed?

Comment: I edited the answer to gives you an example. Please upvote the answer if it helps you.

Comment: your Edit would work, considering all the QPushButtons had different names, but since I it's just a column of "+" buttons, they all have the same text.

Comment: I tried that, but it only sets the text for the last QLineEdit :/

Comment: My mistake... Make sure `itemCount` is local (without `self`) and it should work.